# Full screen centered background responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, background-image

I'm looking to make my homepage a full screen centered background image, where it doesn't matter what screen size the device is, the image always covers the entire page and with the correct aspect ratio. I'd also like it to work across various devices.

I've seen various different ways to do this but i just don't seem to get the effect that i'm looking for. So i'm either doing things incorrectly or i just haven't found/thought about a solution that works.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Try the above code and switch `html` with any other element as required. So if you only want it on the `body` or something for example.

This was taken from this article on CSS Tricks -

[CSS Tricks - Perfect Background Image](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Answer (score 0):

```
.bg {
position: fixed; 
top: -50%; 
left: -50%; 
width: 200%; 
height: 200%;
}
.bg img {
position: absolute; 
top: 0; 
left: 0; 
right: 0; 
bottom: 0; 
margin: auto; 
min-width: 50%;
min-height: 50%;
}
```

Like that, you can still use the html image tag.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.div {
  background: url('images/bg.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

And for responsive layout if you are new to this i suggest using Bootstrap framework.